# .NET is there a way to discover the members of a COM-object

Tags: .net, com

In our WPF-application that is hosted in IE we are retrieving some context info from a COM-object which has the type of System.__ComObject (JScriptTypeInfo).
We retrieve data from it using its type:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
object value = type.InvokeMember(name, BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase, null, obj, null);
```

where **name** is the property we want to retrieve.
The problem is that some properties are retrieved but some are not - an exception is thrown (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
(0x80020006): Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))

So is it possible to retrieve the names of all the properties of this COM-object and how?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample to use ITypeInfo to get the type information of an automation object in .Net can be found at [Inspecting COM Objects With Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347981.aspx)